# Best approach to connect two nodejs REST API servers

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket

Scenario is I have two Node applications which are providing some REST APIs, Server_A has some set of REST endpoints, and Server_B has some other set of endpoints.

We have a requirement where Server_A need some data from Server_B. We can create some REST endpoints for this but there will be some performance issues. Server_A will create http connection each time to Server_B.

We can use Websockets but I am not much sure if it would be good approach or not.
In all cases Server_A will be calling Server_B and Server_B will return data instantly.

Server_B will be doing most of the database operations, Server_A has calculations only. Server_A will call Server_B for some data requirements.

In Addition, there will be only one socket connection that is between Server_A and Server_B, all other clients will connect via REST only.

Could anyone suggest if it would be correct approach?
Or you have some better idea.

It would be helpful if I get some code references, modules suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: do you have some prepared data on Server B or you have to make calculations etc ?

Comment: Well, Server_B will be doing most of the database operations, Server_A has calculations only.

Server_A will call Server_B for some data requirements.
In Addition, there will be only one socket connection that is between Server_A and Server_B, all other clients will connect via REST only.

Comment: I dont think websocket is usable for your case. I do not know the use case but using Redis in the middle as a cache might be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about is premature optimization.  You are attempting to optimize before you even know you have a problem.

HTTP connections are pretty darn fast.  There are databases that work using an HTTP API and those databases are consulted on every HTTP request of the server.  So, an HTTP API that is used frequently can work just fine.

What you need to do is to implement your server A using the regular HTTP requests to server B that are already supported.  Then, test your system at load and see how it performs.  Chances are pretty good that the real bottleneck won't have anything to do with the fact that you're using HTTP requests between server A and server B and if you want to improve the performance of your system, you will probably be working on different problems.  This is why you don't want to do premature optimization.

The more moving parts in a system, the less likely you have any idea where the actual bottlenecks are when you put the system under load.  That's why you have to test the system under load, instrument it like crazy so you can see where the performance is being impacted the most and then measure like crazy.  Then, and only then, will you know where it makes sense to invest your development resources to improve your scalablity or performance.

FYI, a webSocket connection has some advantages over repeated HTTP connections (less connection overhead per request), but also some disadvantages (it's not request/response so you have invent your own way to match a response with a given request).

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, I totally agree with you but still there will be several calls in between  servers, and each call will require authentication.

I agree with you the it will not take much time but I still need to make a connection between two apps and it should not be http.
I am open to other options rather then sockets.

Comment: @A_J - Auth can be done just fine with HTTP on every request if you want. Your bank does that just fine on every HTTP request once you login. You could use a cookie or a token in a custom header for a credential.  If you've already decided that you're not going to use HTTP (for reasons I don't understand), then a webSocket works just fine, but you will have to design your own request/response system so you know which response goes with which request.  And, if you ever want to cluster for scaling, you will have to figure out how to engineer that yourself too.

Comment: @A_J - And, with webSocket, you'd have to do a bunch of reliability stuff to detect when the connection has gone bad and automatically re-establish the connection.  All things you don't have to implement yourself with HTTP.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, 
could you suggest any other option to connect the two apps?

Or just to call a function of Server_B from Server_A?